# to run the application you need to install.net core

Tags: vb.net

i am  abegeinner in vb.net and i am facing a major issue .

me and my team are working on the project where we divided the work of designging and backend
now i have my project in my pc and my friend have shared me his project file
i am trying to run my friends project in my pc but its show this error :to run the application you need to install.net core i have  installed the .netcore but still i am getting the same error why is this hapenning.is there any another way to run this file or merge the project with my project

Comment: You started developing different parts of the same project without agreeing on the framework version?

Comment: You would benefit from using GitHub for version control and sharing the project from inside Visual Studio. You could start learning about it at [Get started with Git and GitHub in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/visual-studio-github-push/).